Positioning tooltip on polygon in leaflet
I am trying to put permanent tooltip on the center of polygons on a leaflet map but they still are far from the polygon... Even if I change offset.
My code (in onEachFeature function) is :
        layer.bindTooltip(
        feature.properties.label,
        {
            permanent: true,
            direction: 'left',
            offset: L.point({x: 100, y: 0}),
            //className: 'labelIlot',
            opacity: 0.7
        }
    ).openTooltip();

I get :

the tooltips are very far from the polygon...
I tried to find the coord of the center of the polygon (getBounds().getCenter()) and to put a marker. it works

but.. when I put the tooltip on the marker, it is still far from the marker... why ?
And sometimes, I have multipolygons.... I would like a tooltip by part of polygon...
I tried the plugin https://github.com/ZijingPeng/leaflet-tooltip-layout?tab=readme-ov-file but it didn't works...
Thank's.

Can you please post more of your code. In particular, can you please post the code that draws the polygons. Ideally a working code snippet or jsfiddle would be useful.
